# Finding total number of combinations from list of buckets in each feature

Tags: combinatorics

I have 3 features `age`, `income` and `rating`.

In case of age I have 3 buckets.

for income I have 4 buckets.

and for rating I have 2 buckets.

If one could filter data where a person could select 1 or more than 1 bucket from each feature what would be the total number of combinations that can be selected?

E.g

```
Age = [less than 18, 18 < age <= 30, greater than 30]
Rating = [Low, High]

Combination_1 = [less than 18, Low]
Combination_2 = [18 < age <= 30, Low]
Combination_3 = [greater than 30, Low]
Combination_4 = [less than 18, High]
Combination_5 = [18 < age <= 30, High]
Combination_6 = [greater than 30, High]
Combination_7 = [less than 18, None]
Combination_8 = [18 < age <= 30, None]
Combination_9 = [greater than 30, None]
Combination_10 = [None, Low]
Combination_11 = [None, High]
Combination_12 = [None,None]
```

In this example there will be 12 combinations. What would be a generalized formula to achieve this?
Here `None` represents nothing is filtered from the feature.

Edit:
`None` here is not a feature but just a representation to tell it can be possible that nothing is selected.

```
Combination_1 = [less than 18, Low]
Combination_2 = [18 < age <= 30, Low]
Combination_3 = [greater than 30, Low]
Combination_4 = [less than 18, High]
Combination_5 = [18 < age <= 30, High]
Combination_6 = [greater than 30, High]
Combination_7 = [less than 18, None]
Combination_8 = [18 < age <= 30, None]
Combination_9 = [greater than 30, None]
Combination_10 = [None, Low]
Combination_11 = [None, High]
Combination_12 = [None,None]
```

As one could select more than 1 bucket from each feature following combinations are also possible.

```
Combination_13 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30], Low]
Combination_14 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30], high]
Combination_15 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30], None]

Combination_16 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30, greater than 30], Low]
Combination_17 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30, greater than 30], high]
Combination_18 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30, greater than 30], None]

Combination_19 = [less than 18, [High,Low]]
Combination_20 = [18 < age <= 30, [High,Low]]
Combination_21 = [greater than 30, [High,Low]]

Combination_22 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30], [High,Low]]
Combination_23 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30], [High,Low]]
Combination_24 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30], [High,Low]]

Combination_25 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30, greater than 30], [High,Low]]
Combination_26 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30, greater than 30], [High,Low]]
Combination_27 = [[less than 18,18 < age <= 30, greater than 30], [High,Low]]
```

Comment: I request clarification re "... could select 1 or more than 1 bucket from each feature..." which suggests that at least 1 bucket from each feature is suggested.  However, in your example, you showed Combination_12, which suggests that you are allowed to ignore both the Age and Rating features.  It is as if you have **added** the *None* attribute to the group of age features and added the *None* attribute to the group of rating features.  Before I can give a hint or an answer, I need clarification on this point.

Comment: You say you have two choices for rating but I see you are using "none" too. So you really have $3$ choices for rating. Also as an example, if the age is less than 18, what are the options for income? Think of any such dependencies.

Comment: @MathLover +1, re "...dependencies."  That one got past me.

Comment: @user2661923 I just added to your note. I think the most imp clarification required is how he is choosing only some features and not all.

Comment: @user2661923  I've made an edit where I've added more combinations that are possible given the statement  "... could select 1 or more than 1 bucket from each feature...". `None` in the combination represents nothing was selected form that feature

Comment: @user2661923 you've correctly pointed out that "none" too is an option and for rating there would be 3 choices `High` `Low` and `None`.

Comment: I am posting this as a comment rather than an answer because I am unsure that I have interpreted you correctly.  First I would calculate $n = (3 + 4 + 2) = 9.$  Then I would compute the # of possibilities as $2^n = 2^9.$  This is based on the idea that you have (in effect 9 distinct attributes), each of which you may or may not select.  Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: @Daniel please check your combinations $10, 11, 12$ - there is no age. What would that mean?

Comment: So I could have any $2$ of the $3$ in my list or all $3$? - Age, Income, Rating? I am trying to understand valid list attributes.

Comment: @MathLover it is possible that you select nothing form age bucket. Also you select from either 1 feature or 2 features or 3 features or you don't make a selection at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on all clarifications in comments, here is how you can look at the number of combinations -

Each dropdown value in the feature can be independently selected - there are $2$ options - either it is selected or not selected = 2 ways.

So for Age feature $= 2^3$ combinations, as there are $3$ dropdown values. If none the values are selected, that is included in $2^3$ combinations.

For Income feature $= 2^4$ combinations.

For Rating feature $ = 2^2$ combinations.

So total number of combinations $= 2^3 \times 2^4 \times 2^2 = 2^9 = 512$ combinations.

Please note this includes a case if none of the values from any of the features are selected (i.e. no feature is selected).

Comment: if I use this formula on example mentioned in question. I get 32 combinations however there should be 27. $$2^5 - 5 = 27$$

Comment: @Daniel Yes it will be 32. You may be missing some. Let me go through the example in your question to see which one's are you missing.

Comment: Only "18 < age <= 30, greater than 30", where are those combinations for example? I did not seem them.

Answer (score 1):

- There are
  $$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\dots+\binom{n}{n}\\=(1+1)^n\\=2^n$$ mutually
  exclusive-ways of selecting any number (including zero) of buckets
  from $n$ buckets.

  Since the $m$ features are independent (i.e., the choice of bucket(s)
  from each feature is regardless of the choice of    bucket(s) from
  the    other features) and each contains $n$ buckets, there are $$2^{n_1} \times 2^{n_2}    \times \dots \times
     2^{n_m}\\=2^{n_1+\dots+n_m}$$    combinations in total.

  So for the case at hand (3, 4 & 2 buckets across the three features),
  there are $$2^{3+4+2}\\=512$$ combinations in total.
- Or, more simply, there are $$\binom{n_1+\dots+n_m}{0}+\binom{n_1+\dots+n_m}{1}+\dots+\binom{n_1+\dots+n_m}{n_1+\dots+n_m}\\=2^{n_1+\dots+n_m}$$ mutually-exclusive ways of selecting any number (including zero) of buckets from $(n_1+\dots+n_m)$ buckets.
- Even more straightforward is @user2661923 's framing in the comments: the $(n_1+\dots+n_m)$ buckets can each be independently categorised in $2$ ways — Pick or Reject — so $$2^{n_1+\dots+n_m}$$ combinations in total.